# How can I animate tab switching in Jetpack Compose TabRow to be similar to WhatsApp?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How to make smooth tabs switching indicator in tabRow in jetpack compose similar to whatsapp?

```
@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class, ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
fun TabRowHorizontalPager(
    pagerState: PagerState,
    fancyIndicator: @Composable (List<TabPosition>) -> Unit,
    titles: List<String>,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    scrollBehavior: TopAppBarScrollBehavior,
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    TabRow(
        selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
        containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
        contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
        indicator = fancyIndicator,
    ) {
        titles.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
            Tab(
                selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
                onClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)
                    }
                },
                text = {
                    Text(
                        text = title,
                        maxLines = 2,
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    }
    HorizontalPager(
        pageCount = 3,
        state = pagerState,
        modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection)
    ) { tabIndex ->
        when (tabIndex) {
            0 -> ChatsTabContent(navController = navController)
            1 -> StatusTabContent(navController = navController)
            2 -> CallsTabContent(navController = navController)
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun IndicatorHome(
    index: PagerState,
    tabPositions: List<TabPosition>,
    tabColors: List<Color> = listOf()
) {
    val selectedTabIndex = index.currentPage
    val colors = tabColors.ifEmpty { listOf(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface) }
    val transition = updateTransition(selectedTabIndex, label = "")
    val indicatorStart by transition.animateDp(
        transitionSpec = {
            if (initialState < targetState) {
                spring(dampingRatio = 1f, stiffness = 50f)
            } else {
                spring(dampingRatio = 1f, stiffness = 1000f)
            }
        }, label = ""
    ) {
        tabPositions[it].left
    }

    val indicatorEnd by transition.animateDp(
        transitionSpec = {
            if (initialState < targetState) {
                spring(dampingRatio = 1f, stiffness = 1000f)
            } else {
                spring(dampingRatio = 1f, stiffness = 50f)
            }
        }, label = ""
    ) {
        tabPositions[it].right
    }

    val indicatorColor by transition.animateColor(label = "") {
        colors[it % colors.size]
    }

    FancyIndicator(
        indicatorColor,
        modifier = Modifier
            
            .fillMaxSize()
            .wrapContentSize(align = Alignment.BottomStart)
            .offset(x = indicatorStart, y = 0.dp)
            .width(indicatorEnd - indicatorStart)
    )
}

@Composable
fun FancyIndicator(indicatorColor: Color, modifier: Modifier) {
    TabRowDefaults.Indicator(modifier, color = indicatorColor, height = 4.dp)
}
```

[image]

This is the Result I'm getting

[image]

This is Expected Result

I tried to make homeScreen smilar to whatsapp but tab is not animating with slight change in the pager state and it is animating when page has changed.

It should animate and move it's position on the tabRow with even litte bit of sliding.

Comment: Please post the different animation effect gif between the two

Comment: posted the GIF and I tried the different approaches to this but it's not working